# Avoiding newline after "Table" in caption while using IEEETran

Tags: captions, ieeetran

IEEETran has the following style for table caption:

```
Table <number>  
<caption>
```

But I would like to have it, without a line-break, as:

```
Table <number>. <caption>
```

This would also be consistent with the caption style for figures. Is it possible?

Comment: Load the package `caption`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If allowed to perform such alteration to a paper's documentclass, you should use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to modify the table caption formatting. Try adding

```
...
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\captionsetup[table]{format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=period}%
...
```

to your document preamble. If there is a marginal difference between other float captions and the redefinition using the `caption` package, then you can redefine those ones as well for consistency. There are, in fact, a multitude of other caption formatting options available. Read the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

caption package conflicts with IEEEtran template 
open ieeeconf.cls and find:

```
\begin{center}{\footnotesize #1}\\{\footnotesize\scshape #2}\end{center}%
```

change to:

```
\begin{center}{\footnotesize #1: }{\footnotesize\scshape #2}\end{center}%
```